# Excel Pivot Table-Hiding specific Column Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that looks like below.

```
Critical        
Yes No  Total
1   3   4
1   2   3
3   0   3
4   1   5
```

I need to Hide the No column from the pivot but shouldn't impact total column. I have tried using Hide "No" column but that changes the value in Total field.
TIA.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the current pivot table and then delete the No column?

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim. There is no option to remove one of the possible value under critical. I can remove Critical Column completely, that would remove yes & total Also.

Comment: No...you missed the point of my comment.  Why do you need to "hide" the No column?  If you just need to _display_ the pivot table with No hidden, then just copy the table and remove that column.

Comment: Can't you hide the column itself? http://imgur.com/a/sSUxf

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that may serve the purpose provided that there are limited no. of column.. But my pivot is quite big & then I need to do such customizations very often. This is tedious & prone to error.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri, if i hide the No column, then the subtotals column doesn't consider the value while summing it up.

Comment: No it will consider, see i did it here http://imgur.com/a/nRUV9

Comment: What does your input data look like?  This could be achieved with a custom field, but that depends on how the data that makes up the pivot table is constructed.

Comment: @Hambone, didn't understand your query.. :( There are diversified set of user updating the data in sharepoint... It looks like above itself.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri.. Doesn't work for me... Maybe you can help me with the process. Here is my current data

  Total Grand Total
No Yes  
 8 8 8
2 8 10 10
 1 1 1
7 3 10 10
 1 1 1
 1 1 1
5 3 8 8
1 2 3 3
15 27 42 42


 Total Grand Total
Yes  
8 8 8
8 8 8
1 1 1
3 3 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
3 3 3
2 2 2
27 27 27

Comment: @RehbanKhatri, sry if it looks plain text, I am not able to put it in a tabular form.

Comment: Just hide the whole column by dragging the top column border and pull it towards the left side, it will hide itself